# Change screen resolution without monitor programmatically under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, screen-resolution, xrandr

I'm writing a GUI program which will be executed along the OS (`CentOS 6.6`) boots.

The resolution configuration is programmed in the `init` part of the GUI program, my solution right now is get the resolution sets of the monitor using `xrandr` and parse the result and set it to one of the candidates,  you can choose one of them in the `Preferences` part of the GUI program later. But `xrandr` won't work if no monitor is plugged in, right?

If I got no monitor plugged into the box, that means I have no idea what the resolution sets one monitor can provide (at least not from `xrandr`), so now what I want is, if I turn on the computer, and the GUI program will be executed, after plugging a monitor later, I can see the GUI program already loaded in the monitor.

I mean I want the resolution fixed (`1152x864 75.0Hz`, for example) in the GUI program init part using some commands or APIs if no monitor plugged?

Does anyone know anything about the available `commands` or `APIs`?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this with/without a monitor, but it should be possible to "prime" outputs without a display connected with `xrandr`.

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x768_2" 63.50 1024 1072 1176 1328 768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
```

to define a new, fixed mode since we can't use EDID with no monitor connected(make sure the name is unique). Also make sure you define a mode any thinkable monitor will be capable displaying (which pretty much limits you to small resolution VESA compatible modes, otherwise you risk damaging old fixed frequency monitors).

```
xrandr --addmode <output device> 1024x768_2
```

to assign this mode to a graphics card output

```
xrandr --output <output device> 1024x768_2
```

to enable this output.

set this the primary display

```
xrandr --primary <output device>
```